# Avoiding instanceof with Generics

Tags: java, generics

I need to add to a List of child attributes (ProductOption and ProductAttribute) that are a property of a parent object called Product.  All three classes extend an abstract class CMS.

I want to call the method "attachChildToParent" generically, but I am delaying the inevitable by deferring the `instanceof` and cast to the Product.

Is there a way I can write this generically so I can avoid the cast?

To Test:

```
package puzzler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product p = new Product();
        ProductAttribute pa = new ProductAttribute();
        ProductOffering po = new ProductOffering();

        List<ProductAttribute> lpa = new ArrayList<ProductAttribute>();
        List<ProductOffering> lpo = new ArrayList<ProductOffering>();

        attachChildToParent(lpa, p);
    }

    static void attachChildToParent(List<? extends CMS> listChild, Product parent) {
        for (CMS cmsItem : listChild) {
            parent.attach(cmsItem);         
        }
    }
}
```

The Product class (parent)

```
package puzzler;

import java.util.List;

abstract class CMS {
    String node;
}
public class Product extends CMS {
    List<ProductAttribute> lpa;
    List<ProductOffering> lpo;

    public List<ProductAttribute> getLpa() {
        return lpa;
    }

    public void setLpa(List<ProductAttribute> lpa) {
        this.lpa = lpa;
    }

    public List<ProductOffering> getLpo() {
        return lpo;
    }

    public void setLpo(List<ProductOffering> lpo) {
        this.lpo = lpo;
    }

    public void attach(ProductAttribute childNode) {
        this.getLpa().add(childNode);
    }

    public void attach(ProductOffering childNode) {
        this.getLpo().add(childNode);
    }

    //  I want to avoid this.  Defeats the purpose of generics.
    public void attach(CMS cms) {
        if (cms instanceof ProductOffering) {
            this.getLpo().add((ProductOffering) cms);
        } else         {
            if (cms instanceof ProductAttribute) {
                this.getLpa().add((ProductAttribute) cms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child class 1

```
package puzzler;

import puzzler.CMS;

public class ProductAttribute extends CMS {
    String node;

    public String getNode() {
        return node;
    }

    public void setNode(String node) {
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```

Child class 2

```
package puzzler;

import puzzler.CMS;

public class ProductOffering extends CMS {
    String node;

    public String getNode() {
        return node;
    }

    public void setNode(String node) {
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't been using java for ages, but in C# you can do declaration like this:

   FatherType foo = new ChildType();

and 

   List<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work around the casting by using the visitor pattern: in your `CMS` class, add a new (abstract) method `attachTo(Product parent)`.  In each of the sub-classes, you can implement this method to call attach on the parent, and the right function will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate to the sub classes:

```
public void attach(CMS cms) {
    cms.callAdd(this);

}
```

On CMS add:

```
public abstract void callAdd(Product product);
```

And on ProductOffering add:

```
public void callAdd(Product product) {
   getLpo().add(this)       
}
```

An similarly for ProductAttribute...

Answer (score 0):

Override?

```
public void attach(ProductOffering cms) {
   this.getLpo().add(cms);
}

public void attach(ProductAttribute cms) {
   this.getLpa().add(cms);
}
```

Comment: This code already exists: the issue is that the call-site only knows about the super-class, it doesn't disambiguate at run-time.

Comment: Doh!  Sorry for the quickfire answer I just had a proper look and you are right.  I don't think generics will help due to run-time type erasure.  I'll have a think but because you have a logical branch you need to differentiate the actual implementation at runtime when it is passed into the method.  You might have to rethink this further up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to avoid this but not with generics. Generics allow you to write code which allows to avoid casts but it doesn't help when you need to avoid `instanceof`. The main reason is that all variables with a generic type are treated as `Object` internally.

And this is why the compiler uses the generic `attach(CMS)` method when you call it from `attachChildToParent()`: The type of the children to attach will be `CMS` - there is no way for the compiler to preserve the type that you use when you call `attachChildToParent()`.

The only solution is to write an attach method in the children:

```
public class ProductAttribute extends CMS {
    @Override
    public void attachTo( Product p ) {
        p.getLpo().add( this );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was my original approach, but it assumes that the parent is always Product.  In reality, that will probably always be the case, and I am over-thinking this.  But the puzzle does bother me.

Comment: You can also create an interface and use that as parameter type in `attachTo()`. That would allow you to say "this child can be attached to anything which has the method `getLpo()`"

Answer (score 0):

Generics can not solve your problem. Since you loose instance specific information after `<? extends CMS>` that all elements in List are children of `CMS` only.

Why not add simple method which takes both list as parameters which fits in your design and solves your problem also it is efficient

```
public void attach(List<ProductAttribute> lpa, List<ProductOffering> lpo) {
    this.lpa.addAll(lpa);
    this.lpo.addAll(lpo);
}
```